# Ajuda em plotar gráfico de função em R

Tags: r

estava tentando fazer uma função que fizesse a derivada de uma função e consegui, porém queria também plotar o gráfico da derivada e está apresentando erro. Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

```
differentiation<- function(x){

  z <- D(substitute(x),"x")

  print(z)

  curve(z,-5,5)

}
```

```
Error in z(x) : could not find function "z"
```

Se tirar o `curve(z,-5,5)` a função roda normalmente e encontra a derivada em relação a X.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Dê um exemplo de chamada da função, por favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O objecto `z` é um objecto de classe `"call"` e deve ser avaliado para se tornar uma função.

```r
differentiation <- function(x, from = -5, to = 5){
  z <- D(substitute(x), "x")
  print(z)
  do.call(curve, list(expr = z, from = from, to = to))
} 

differentiation(x^2 + 3*x + 2)
#> 2 * x + 3
```

[image]

```r
differentiation(sin(x))
#> cos(x)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>